# C++ class specifier alignas option via template

Tags: c++, alignas

Can C++ template parameters be used to control specifiers on the class itself to minimize some code duplication?

For example: I have a class that I'd like to use both in a concurrent context (and container) with the `alignas` specifier, and also in a single-threaded context without the `alignas` specifier. The size of the class is small (20B) -- less than a cache line. I do need to copy between the two classes. Right now I have duplicated code for the two definitions of the two classes which are the same, mostly, other than the said specifier. Can templates or otherwise allow a single definition, one with `alignas` and one without?

Comment: Why does the concurrent context require `alignas`?

Comment: Will you be using the class with and without the `alignas` specifier in a single project?

Comment: You say that you need to be able to copy between two versions of the class. But keep in mind that templates are not inheritance. So they are treated as a completely different class once the compilation actually starts.

Comment: @Eugene to prevent false-sharing in a producer-consumer situation

Comment: @NathanOliver yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
template <size_t alignment = 0>
class alignas(alignment) C {
    // ...
};
```

Now `C<>` will have the default alignment for its definition (since `alignas(0)` is ignored) while you could use *e.g.* `C<16>` to force an alignment of 16.